# Array creation, why does this work?

Tags: javascript

I understand why :

```
 output = new Array();
```

and

```
 output = [];
```

but why does this work?

```
 output = Array();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Array()` constructor is simply implemented such that calling it with `new` is unnecessary.  It's part of its semantic definition.

Built-in constructors like `Array()` are (probably) not written in JavaScript, but you can get the same effect in your own code:

```
function MyConstructor() {
  "use strict";
  var newObj = this || {};

  // ...

  return newObj;
}
```

When you invoke with `new`, the constructor will see that's it's got something bound to `this`. If you don't, then `this` will be undefined (because of "use strict"; you could alternatively check to see whether `this` is the global object, which you'd have to do for old IE).

The return value from a constructor is not the value of a `new` expression - that's always the newly-created object. When you call it without `new`, however, the return value will be used.

*edit* — RobG points out in a comment that for this to really work properly, the "synthetic" `newObj` that the function creates needs to be explicitly set up so that it's got the proper prototype etc. That's kind-of tricky; it might be simplest for the code to simply do this:

```
function MyConstructor() {
  "use strict";
  if (!this) return new MyConstructor();
  // ... or possibly using "apply" if you need parameters too
}
```

T.J. Crowder has written some awesome answers here on the subject of object/inheritance wrangling.

Comment: I don't think that's correct. If `MyConstructor` isn't called with `new`, `newObj` won't inherit from it. The function needs to return an instance of `MyConstructor` (and not all or user agents browsers support strict mode).

Comment: @RobG yes sorry; of course you're correct. I left out that part in the interest of simplicity but I meant to state that explicitly :-)

Answer (score 1):

A function such as `Array()` can be written to detect whether it was called without the `new` operator and if `new` was omitted automatically create a new object and then return it.

Answer (score 0):

The trivial answer is "because ECMA-262 says so". RTFM.

The first calls the [Array function as a constructor](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.2), the second is an [Array initialiser](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.1.4) (aka Array literal).

The third is calling the [Array function as a function](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.1) and is equivalent to `new Array()` and `[]`.

Answer (score 0):

output = Array() works because Array is a function.

Run this cod3

```
<script>
var a = new Array();
var b = Array();
a[0] = 123;
b[0] = 32;
alert("a = " + a +"\nb = " +b +", " + Array);
</script>
```

This prints out:

```
a = 123
b = 32, function Array() {
    [native code]
}
```

So, since Array is a function, you can call Array(), which its implementation is to give you back a new Array()